ROUGE-L score example and the corresponding ROUGE-n where n = length of longest common substring
I am following this video on ROUGE score and he goes over ROUGE-1, ROUGE-2 and ROUGE-L. I was able to calculate the first 2 and confirm with the answers of the video but there wasn't an answer given for ROUGE-L.



Is this the correct way of calculating ROUGE-L?

precision = 1/3
recall = 1/5
ROUGE-L (F1 score) = (2 * 1/3 * 1/5) / (1/3 + 1/5) = 2/8 = 0.25

(Assuming the above ROUGE-L value is correct) As the longest common substring is a bigram, how does the ROUGE-L compare with ROUGE-2 = 0.33 (shown here in the video)? Which one is a better metric?

